# How to add mysql skip name resolve

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have to connect to my MYSQL server via remote connection from my pc, 
The connection works. But its too slow.

From my reasearch I heard adding a line,

```
skip name resolve
```

is going to speed it up. 
But where to add this? And how?

I am using mysql 5.7 with Ubuntu 16.04.
Is there any tutorial or something for this? I am noob.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Add option `skip-name-resolve` in your config file.
2. Add cmd line `option --skip-name-resolve` when you start `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe`.

Comment: But still the same. Is this what you meant?

`sudo service mysql start --skip-name-resolve`

Comment: if your os is ubuntu, you can start your mysql using the cmd line . Run mysqld or mysqld_safe with the option --skip-name-resolve. Just like bellow:

Comment: shell> /../../mysqld --defauts-file=.../your config --skip-name-resolve

Answer (score 29):

Edit the below metioned file and add the  given code.

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` OR For Ubuntu16.* `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
```

And restart MySQL server using below command.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Config file was : /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. But still the same.

Comment: @humbleiam try this command to restart you mysql server `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`. Let me know what is actual error do you have now ?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16 the file to edit is `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Comment: If I did add `skip-name-resolve`: 1. Should I use server IP address to connect remotely to the database? 2. Should I update my user host values in mysql.user table with IP addresses instead of host name?